# Spring Boot accessing data with SQL. Example, web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use Error

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, runtime-error

I tried to change tomcat default port 8080 to 8181 or 9090 or 9191 all ports give me same error, I tried to kill process that working on port 8080 but I am taking same error. Also, I try to
java -jar target/accessing-data-mysql-initial-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --server.port=

This is Error Message;

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.0)

2022-08-27 17:54:17.231  INFO 2555 --- [           main] c.example.accessingdatamysql.FTtechApp   : Starting FTtechApp v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 18.0.2.1 on Furkan-MacBook-Pro-2.local with PID 2555 (/Users/furkangulenc/Downloads/gs-accessing-data-mysql-main/initial/target/accessing-data-mysql-initial-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by furkangulenc in /Users/furkangulenc)
2022-08-27 17:54:17.235  INFO 2555 --- [           main] c.example.accessingdatamysql.FTtechApp   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-08-27 17:54:17.972  INFO 2555 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-08-27 17:54:18.032  INFO 2555 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 51 ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-08-27 17:54:18.794  INFO 2555 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-08-27 17:54:18.808  INFO 2555 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-08-27 17:54:18.808  INFO 2555 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.63]
2022-08-27 17:54:18.886  INFO 2555 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-08-27 17:54:18.886  INFO 2555 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1581 ms
2022-08-27 17:54:19.160  INFO 2555 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-08-27 17:54:19.227  INFO 2555 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.9.Final
2022-08-27 17:54:19.427  INFO 2555 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-08-27 17:54:19.533  INFO 2555 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-08-27 17:54:19.872  INFO 2555 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-08-27 17:54:19.901  INFO 2555 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2022-08-27 17:54:20.526  INFO 2555 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-08-27 17:54:20.535  INFO 2555 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-08-27 17:54:20.814  WARN 2555 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-08-27 17:54:21.122  WARN 2555 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.PortInUseException: Port 8080 is already in use
2022-08-27 17:54:21.124  INFO 2555 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-08-27 17:54:21.126  INFO 2555 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-08-27 17:54:21.133  INFO 2555 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2022-08-27 17:54:21.135  INFO 2555 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-08-27 17:54:21.144  INFO 2555 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-08-27 17:54:21.162 ERROR 2555 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use.

Action:

Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8080 or configure this application to listen on another port.

Furkan-MacBook-Pro-2:~ furkangulenc$  java -jar /Users/furkangulenc/Downloads/gs-accessing-data-mysql-main/initial/target/accessing-data-mysql-initial-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.0)

2022-08-27 18:01:06.612  INFO 2657 --- [           main] c.example.accessingdatamysql.FTtechApp   : Starting FTtechApp v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 18.0.2.1 on Furkan-MacBook-Pro-2.local with PID 2657 (/Users/furkangulenc/Downloads/gs-accessing-data-mysql-main/initial/target/accessing-data-mysql-initial-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by furkangulenc in /Users/furkangulenc)
2022-08-27 18:01:06.618  INFO 2657 --- [           main] c.example.accessingdatamysql.FTtechApp   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-08-27 18:01:07.292  INFO 2657 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-08-27 18:01:07.348  INFO 2657 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 45 ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-08-27 18:01:07.999  INFO 2657 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-08-27 18:01:08.011  INFO 2657 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-08-27 18:01:08.011  INFO 2657 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.63]
2022-08-27 18:01:08.092  INFO 2657 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-08-27 18:01:08.092  INFO 2657 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1408 ms
2022-08-27 18:01:08.287  INFO 2657 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-08-27 18:01:08.348  INFO 2657 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.9.Final
2022-08-27 18:01:08.550  INFO 2657 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-08-27 18:01:08.652  INFO 2657 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-08-27 18:01:09.004  INFO 2657 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-08-27 18:01:09.041  INFO 2657 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2022-08-27 18:01:09.651  INFO 2657 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-08-27 18:01:09.658  INFO 2657 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-08-27 18:01:09.912  WARN 2657 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-08-27 18:01:10.282  WARN 2657 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.PortInUseException: Port 8080 is already in use
2022-08-27 18:01:10.283  INFO 2657 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-08-27 18:01:10.285  INFO 2657 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-08-27 18:01:10.293  INFO 2657 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2022-08-27 18:01:10.294  INFO 2657 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-08-27 18:01:10.305  INFO 2657 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-08-27 18:01:10.330 ERROR 2657 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use.

Action:

Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8080 or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

This is my application.properties file;

```
   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/db_example
   spring.datasource.username=springuser
   spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
   spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
   spring.jpa.show-sql: true
   spring.main.web-application-type=none
   logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure=ERROR
```

This is my pom.xml file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>accessing-data-mysql-initial</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>accessing-data-mysql-initial</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                
            </plugin>
        
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And its my Folders;

[Spring Boot Accessing Data with MySql Guides Folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzeL7.png)

Comment: which IDE are you using? `invalidate cache restart` maybe help.

Comment: I am using Eclipse IDE. I tried but not working

Comment: did you change port as using `server.port=8081` in application.properties right? and check for which application using 8080 port, running this command in powershell `netstat -a -o -n`

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a process is using 8080 port

Either change spring embedded tomcat port by setting application.properties
e.g. `server.port=8081`

or

Stop the process occupying port 8080